# VS Installer - getmac

Tags: visual-studio

I couldn't think of a better place to ask, so I put my question here, even though it doesn't concern programming directly.

In the past few months I have installed Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 twice and every time I ran the VS installer, a command line window with getmac popped up, so I assume that this is just part of the installer.

I am nevertheless suspicious. Can anyone confirm that or even explain why the installer runs getmac?

Comment: All you had to do is *literally [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=VS+Installer+-+getmac&oq=VS+Installer+-+getmac&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.809j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)*. Even if this question *were* on-topic (which it isn't), it would be closed as too broad.

Comment: Thanks, I did google it, but there seems to be no answer as to why getmac is run, leaving aside that in the first hit only an instruction is given how to check if it's part of VS.